# Multiple Table MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which i want to query at the same time. The tables are uploads and audienceuploadassociation, so here is the thing, i have only 1 topic value called "ESL" in my table, but when i use the SQL below it give me 6 records, it repeats the same data 6 times.

```
SELECT uploads.*, audienceuploadassociation.*
FROM   uploads
  JOIN audienceuploadassociation
    ON uploads.upload_id = audienceuploadassociation.upload_id
 WHERE uploads.member_id = '1'
   AND uploads.member_school_id='1'
   AND subject = 'ESL'
   AND topic = 'Poetry'
LIMIT  20
```

Here is the table structure for uploads :

```
`uploads` (
  `upload_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `upload_name` text NOT NULL,
  `upload_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `upload_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `topic` longtext NOT NULL,
  `year` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Finished','Work in progress','Blank template') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Finished',
  `test_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `member_display_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `member_school_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`upload_id`)
)
```

and for audienceuploadassociation :

```
`audienceuploadassociation` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `upload_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `audiencename` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you gave table structure and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT uploads.*, audienceuploadassociation.*
FROM   uploads
  JOIN audienceuploadassociation
    ON uploads.upload_id = audienceuploadassociation.upload_id
 WHERE uploads.member_id = '1'
   AND uploads.member_school_id='1'
   AND subject = 'ESL'
   AND topic = 'Poetry'
GROUP BY uploads.upload_id
LIMIT  20
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any relationship between those two tables.

In your `uploads` table definition change this

```
`member_school_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

Remove quote from `member_school_id` since it's a `INT` field.

```
SELECT uploads.*, audienceuploadassociation.*
FROM   uploads
  JOIN audienceuploadassociation
    ON uploads.upload_id = audienceuploadassociation.upload_id
 WHERE uploads.member_id = '1'
   AND uploads.member_school_id=1
   AND uploads.subject = 'ESL'
   AND uploads.topic = 'Poetry'
LIMIT  20
```